# Uploading a file to the server once a user gains access to internet ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, http

I'm building an application who's logic depends on uploading a file to a server. I want to solve the issue in that if a user doesn't have internet connection at the time of file creation, the application will run some kind of background thread(or any other method) to constantly check if the user has gained internet connection, and once he does immediately upload the file. This is for swift ios development. Appreciate any help to be given.

Comment: @Sausage Machine, I think this one is different than that question, there he wanted to post when App is in back ground, but i think here he has asked the app is in fore ground but some task of that app is in background thread. Please rectify me if I have misunderstood his question.
If I correctly understood the question then we can implement the functionality which he wants, by calling the Backend API with the file to be uploaded at the event of internet available, at the time when internet get conected.

Answer (score 0):

How about an approach using Reachability.swift to determine if you have an internet connection and then adding an observer via [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) to upload your files. I believe the examples on the [Reachability GitHub page](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) might achieve what you need.